# Get package name for protobuf instance at runtime in python

Tags: python, protocol-buffers

If I have an instance of a protobuf, is there a way to get the package name from that instance? the [docs](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/python-generated#package) indicate that

> The Python code generated by the protocol buffer compiler is completely unaffected by the package name defined in the .proto file.

Does that mean that there isn't a way to get the package name from a python protobuf instance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I had a protobuf object `response`

```
print type(response)
```

prints

```
<class 'weather_pb2.WeatherReply'>
```

and

```
print response.DESCRIPTOR.full_name
```

prints

```
weather.WeatherReply
```

`weather` being the package name specified where WeatherReply is defined.

Comment: Fantastic. Based on your answer, I found this confirming documentation: https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/python/google.protobuf.descriptor.Descriptor-class